# how to dynamically select package manager in package.json

Tags: npm, package.json, yarnpkg, npm-scripts

I am currently using `yarn` as my package manager, but some people on my team may still use `npm`. I wrote a few scripts in `package.json`

```json
"scripts": {
  "clear": "rm -Rf app/javascripts/* & rm index.html",
  "watch": "yarn clear | NODE_ENV=development webpack -w --env.dev",
  "build": "yarn clear && yarn dev && yarn start",
  "dev": "yarn clear | NODE_ENV=development webpack --env.dev",
  "prod": "yarn clear | NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress --env.prod"
}
```

If I want to call `clear` inside of other scripts, I have to either use `npm clear` or `yarn clear`. As the script is currently written, someone who doesn't have `yarn` installed will run into an error.

Is there a way for me to write this `package.json` so that it will work regardless if someone runs `npm build` or `yarn build`, and it will use the package manager of their choosing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the variable `npm_execpath`, it will point to the package manager used to run the script.

For example, this will output the version of `yarn` or `npm`:

```js
"scripts": {
  "version": "$npm_execpath -v",
}
```

```sh
$ npm run version
> 3.10.10
$ yarn run version
> 0.21.3
```